# JQuery treeview List

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to allow user create own list with tree view, but when I select `ul:last-child` it doesn't run correct also if I not use `ul:last-child` still doesn't run correct. Here is my code snippet

JS Functions;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function addData(){
        let text = "";
        Swal.fire({
            title: 'Add Element',
            input: 'text',
            inputAttributes: {
                autocapitalize: 'off'
            },
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonText: 'Add',
            showLoaderOnConfirm: true,
            cancelButtonText: "Cancel",
            allowOutsideClick: () => !Swal.isLoading()
        }).then((text) => {
            $("#treeview ul").append("<li>"+text.value+"</li>");
        })
    }
    function goSubTitle(){
        $("#treeview ul li").append("<li><ul>");
    }
    function goTitle(){
        $("#treeview ul li").append("</ul></li>");
    }
</script>
```

here screenshots;
[without `ul:last-child`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HRNM8.png)
[with `ul:last-child`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EtNYE.png)

Answer (score 0):

Here is full of HTML codes

```html
<table border style="width: 100%;">
  <tr>
    <td style="width: 30%;">Your List</td>
    <td style="width: 70%;">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8" id="treeview">
          <ul>
          </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-1">
          <button class="btn btn-success" onclick="goTitle()"><</button>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-2">
          <button class="btn btn-success" onclick="addData()">Insert Data</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
          <button class="btn btn-success" onclick="goSubTitle()">></button>
        </div>
      </div>    
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with this changes

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    let code = "";
    let index= 0;
    function addData(){
        let text = "";

        Swal.fire({
            title: 'Enter your value',
            input: 'text',
            inputAttributes: {
                autocapitalize: 'off'
            },
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonText: 'Add',
            showLoaderOnConfirm: true,
            cancelButtonText: "Cancel",
            allowOutsideClick: () => !Swal.isLoading(),
            preConfirm: (text) => {
                code = parseInt($("#treeview li").length);

                $("#treeview ol."+index+":last").append("<li>" + text  + "</li>");
            }
        })
    }

    function goSubTitle() {
        index += 1;
        $("#treeview li:last").append("<ol class="+index+"></ol>");
    }

    function goTitle() {
        index -=1;
        if(index == 0)
        {
            index = 0;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Index started with value of "0" and first ol looks like `<ol class="0"></ol>`.

The reason of the problem, when I try to append `<ul>` or `<li>`, jQuery automatically closes the html tag.